# GNU Emacs customization - no window

Tags: linux, emacs, customization

I am switching to GNU emacs for my python and bash scripting. I really enjoy this, but I don't like the X-window portion of emacs. As such, I always use `emacs -nw <my_file>` to edit my files. However, when I associate my .py and .sh files with emacs, I end up opening emacs in X-window mode when I double-click on them from gnome-nautilus (Ubuntu 10.10).

What I would like to know is: What should I add to my .emacs file in order to use emacs without X-window when I double click on my files? Note: I do want emacs to open a terminal, possibly resize it according to my specifications (already have a .sh script for that), launch itself and open my file.

How should I accomplish that?

Cheers!

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the answers! I have to give the check to the most complete one, although of course it builds on the preceding ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Gareth's answer:

To open a file in an existing emacs session if one is running, but open a new one in a terminal if there isn't one, you can do the following:

1. Add `(server-start)` to your `.emacs`
2. Create a script `run_emacs` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gnome-terminal -e "emacs -nw $@"
   ```

   and make it executable.
3. Set your application to open python and bash files to be `emacsclient -a /path/to/run_emacs %F` (if you place `run_emacs` somewhere in your `$PATH`, you can leave out the `/path/to/` bit).

Comment: Nice @sepp! That totally does the trick for me, thanks :) I also changed my nautilus option to always open executable files upon double-click (instead of asking: 'run-open-else...?'). Makes for a much improved developpement environment. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Johan has explained what to do if you want to launch a separate Emacs process for each file.

But normally, you would want to be running a single Emacs process and arrange that your files be opened in new buffers within the already-running Emacs process.

The way to do this is to start the [Emacs server](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) when you first start Emacs (for example, by running the `server-start` command, or putting `(server-start)` in your `.emacs`) and arranging for Gnome to run the [`emacsclient` program](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html#Invoking-emacsclient).

Comment: @Gareth Nice approach. I added '(server-start)' in my .emacs file. Could you provide with the equivalent of Johan's 'gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/emacs -nw %F"' line for the emacsclient? I tried 'gnome-terminal -e "emacsclient -nw %F"' without success. Cheers!

Comment: See the [emacsclient documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options). The `-nw` option requests `emacsclient` to start a new Emacs for you. You probably just want plain old `emacsclient %F` (no `gnome-terminal`, no `-nw`).

Comment: All right, I'll toy with emacsclient's options. However, your last suggestion (emacsclient %F) requires me to already have an instance of the emacsclient running. Not a big deal but it would be nice if the solution worked by double-clicking on the file, whether or not an emacsclient is already running. Thanks!

Comment: See the `--alternate-editor` argument, which tells `emacsclient` what to do if no Emacs server is running. So: `emacsclient --alternate-editor "gnome-terminal -e 'emacs -nw %F'" %F`

Comment: @Morlock: You can write a little shellscript which runs `gnome-terminal -e "emacs -nw $@"` and then use `emacsclient -a my_emacs_start_script %F` as your command to open files.

Comment: @Gareth: No, that won't work. You can't use `-a` to invoke a command with arguments.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks! Would you please write a short but detailed answer with your suggestion? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you use gnome you need to change the command line option for the emacs shortcut from

/usr/bin/emacs %F

to

gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/emacs -nw %F"

This can be done by right-clicking on the Application menu, select Edit Menus.